# How do I rearrange a non continuous seq number in an Oracle table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with some values and a seq column which orders the values and this gets displayed in the front end, so whenever I delete a record using a function, this seq is not arranged properly.

i.e.

```
col1:
1
2
3
4
5
```

after deletion of 2nd and 4th record. It comes as:

```
Col1:
1
3
5
```

I tried possible ways to re-order it as:

```
Col1:
1
2
3..
```

but its not working 
can some one please help in this?

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are not talking about updating a primary key which is a very bad idea.

Otherwise you can do this

```
update table set col1 = rownum;
```